# List saved networks from Terminal

Tags: wireless, command-line, networking

I'm starting to learn terminal commands and I have one question.

How can I see the list of SAVED networks from Terminal?

**If I go to:**

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

I can see the saved networks listed, but I want use this in a shell script - I'll need this networks listed as a String (or another unique attribute of each network).

### So I want know:

There's any other command to list all saved networks from Terminal? If not, how can I store this unique attribute of each of this networks in Shell Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all your saved networks in an array. Here is an example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a networks #the array where we will store all saved networks
n=0
for network in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*; do
    networks[$n]="$(basename "$network")"
    (( n++ ))
done

#list all networks in a line
echo ${networks[*]}

#list networks one by one
for (( i=0; i<${#networks[@]}; i++ )) {
    echo ${networks[$i]}
}

unset networks
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer friend, it's exactly what I want. However, this return some errors for me: http://notepad.cc/flubbehi75 What's the problem and you can help solve this?

Comment: @FernandoPaladinib It's a bash script, so don't use `sh saved_networks.sh`. Make the script executable using `chmod +x saved_networks.sh` command and run it using this command `./saved_networks.sh` or `bash saved_networks.sh`. See [Creating and running a script](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html)

Comment: Thanks man, this really works! Where I can easily learn Shell Script online? I liked this! The last thing: with this script I can "map" the list of connections to Python object or it just show the name of acess points?

Comment: There are a lot of of guides over the internet to learn shell scripting. Here is one: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/ . If you have more questions, do not hesitate to use [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Thanks, I will see this guide. Can you answer the second question of my comment? If not, I will be glad too :P